# How to Join OPENXML data to my Inner Join Query?

Tags: sql-server-2008, openxml

OpenXML:

```
DECLARE @idoc int
DECLARE @doc varchar(1000)
SET @doc =
'<ROOT>
        <Employee EmployeeID = "1"  EmpStatus = "Full Time"/>
        <Employee EmployeeID = "2"  EmpStatus ="Part Time" />
        </ROOT>'
    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc
SELECT    *
FROM       OPENXML (@idoc, '/ROOT/Employee',1)
            WITH (EmployeeID  varchar(10),
                  EmpStatus varchar(20))
```

Results:

```
EmployeeID    EmpStatus
    1         Full Time
    2         Part Time
```

Table query:

```
    SELECT hr.EmployeeID, hr.Title, c.FirstName,c.LastName 
    FROM HumanResources.Employee hr WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN ContactInfo c WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON hr.ContactID = c.ContactID
    Where hr. EmployeeID IN ( 1, 2)
```

Results:

```
EmployeeID  Title         FirstName  LastName
    1   Engineering   Mike       Brown
    2   Programmer    Yves       Anthony
```

How to join OpenXML data to my inner join query using `EmployeeID`?

Comment: @marc_s thx :-)  I am using SQL Server 2008, sorry I missed that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you **insist** on using OpenXML? It's old, it's legacy - using the native XQuery functions typically is **much easier**.

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @Employees TABLE (EmployeeID INT, Title VARCHAR(20), FirstName VARCHAR(20),LastName VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @Employees VALUES(1, 'Engineering', 'Mike', 'Brown')
INSERT INTO @Employees VALUES(2, 'Programmer', 'Yves', 'Anthony')

DECLARE @doc XML 
SET @doc = '<ROOT>
              <Employee EmployeeID = "1"  EmpStatus = "Full Time"/>
              <Employee EmployeeID = "2"  EmpStatus ="Part Time" />
            </ROOT>'

;WITH XmlCTE AS
(
    SELECT
        EmpID = Empl.value('@EmployeeID', 'int'),
        EmpStatus = Empl.value('@EmpStatus', 'varchar(10)')
    FROM @doc.nodes('/ROOT/Employee') AS Tbl(Empl)
)
SELECT 
    e.*, x.EmpStatus 
FROM 
    @Employees e
INNER JOIN  
    xmlcte x ON e.EmployeeID = x.EmpID
```

This gives me an output of:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! WOW! thanks for the speedy response.  You gave me exactly the info I was looking for and quite fast.  Thank you for sharing your Knowledge!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Despite the other answer implying a level of deprecation in `openxml` that I can find no evidence of, and not bothering to address how to do it anyway... you *can* use `openxml` and `join` at the same time.

In your case, it'd be something like this:

```
select
    x.*,
    hr.EmployeeID, hr.Title, c.FirstName, c.LastName 
from
    openxml (@IDoc, '/ROOT/Employee',1)
    with (
        EmployeeID  varchar(10),
        EmpStatus   varchar(20)
    ) as x
    inner join HumanResources.Employee hr with (nolock) on
        x.EmployeeID = hr.EmployeeID
    inner join Contactinfo c with (nolock)
        on hr.ContactID = c.ContactID;
```

h/t: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=26499&seqNum=3